# Can't set or override on specific header using Angular.js $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js 1.4.8 and Fiddler 4 for debugging my requests.

The following is the request I made using AngularJS `$http`.

```
var postRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize',
    headers: {
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        Expect: '100-continue',
        Expect2: 'abc',
        Accept: 'application/json;text/xml',
        Host: 'region.platform.bing.com',
        'Content-Type': 'audio/wav; samplerate=8000',
        Authorization: 'auth-token',
        'Accept-Language': undefined,
        'Accept-Encoding': undefined,
        'User-Agent': undefined,
    },
    params: {
        scenarios: 'smd', // 'smd' in the internal sample code,
        locale: langString,
        'device.os': 'wp7',
        version: '3.0',
        format: 'json',
    },
    data: "test"
};

$http(postRequest).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

However, as described in below, in the actual request, there are some missing headers (e.g., Expect, Transfer-Encoding). In addition, there are still automatically added headers by Angular even after I set it as undefined (as guided in official document: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$http).

> POST https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?device.os=wp7&format=json&locale=en-US&scenarios=smd&version=3.0 HTTP/1.1
>
> Expect2: abc
>
> Accept: application/json;text/xml
>
> Content-Type: audio/wav; samplerate=8000
>
> Authorization: 'auth-token'
>
> **Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.4,zh-Hans;q=0.2
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate**
>
> **User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; MSAppHost/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240**
>
> Host: speech.platform.bing.com
>
> **Content-Length: 271491** Connection: Keep-Alive Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> **Cookie: MUIDB=39DE0AD21AD46AF2039D02BB1BB26B61**

Is there any ways that

1. Can I add headers which I could not add using 'headers' objects, and
2. Can I remove the headers automatically added by Angular?

Or is it the Angular bug?

Comment: Hi, please read this section of angular maybe help you [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use angular interceptor to handle it globally. So for each request, you can automatically remove the unwanted headers and add necessary headers.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
            return {
                request: function (config) {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    var authData = localStorageService.get('authData');
                    if (authData) {
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                    }

                    return config;
                },

                response: function (result) {
                    return result;
                },

                responseError: function (rejection) {
                    console.log('Failed with', rejection.status, 'status');

                    if (rejection.status == 401) {
                        localStorageService.remove('authData');
                        window.location.replace(window.location.origin)
                    }

                    if (rejection.status == 307) {
                        $location.url('/SessionExpired');
                    }

                    if (rejection.status == 403) {
                        $location.url('/Forbidden');
                    }

                    if (rejection.status == 500) {
                        $location.url('/InternalServerError');
                    }

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            }
        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Setting HTTP Headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
});
```

Comment: This works for 'Authorization' or 'Authentication' header, not for 'Expect', 'Transfer-Encoding'.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, other answers can be misleading ... Yes, using the suggested strategies, you can override some headers but not all! ... The reason of this is that, by [specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader), some headers are reserved and will be controlled only by the browser ... Examples of these reserved headers are:

- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- ...

You can find more information about this in the following urls:

- [AngularJS: Refused to set unsafe header “Access-Control-Request-Headers”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28162228)
- [Forbidden Header name for use with XMLHttpRequest](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)